# Deserializing object references using DataContractSerializer with CollectionDataContract?

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I can't seem to figure out how to use the `CollectionDataContract` attribute properly as soon as object references are involved. Any help is greatly appreciated. Warning: The code example might seem a little long, but I haven't found a way to explain this any shorter, so please bear with me. (**Update: Today I learned that foobar is evil. I stand corrected, so I have replaced all references to "foo" and "bar" with a more meaningful example. Hope this helps.**)

Consider this simple flashcard interface for a hypothetical quiz app:

```
interface IFlashcard
{
    string Question {get; set;}
    string Answer {get; set;}
}
```

It is implemented by classes `Flashcard` and `FlippedFlashcard`. Instances of `FlippedFlashcard` are supposed to keep a reference to a corresponding instance of `Flashcard` in order to reverse `Question` and `Answer` as some of the cards may work in "Jeopardy mode":

```
[DataContract]
class Flashcard : IFlashcard
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Question { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

class FlippedFlashcard : IFlashcard
{
    [DataMember]
    public Flashcard OriginalFlashcard;

    [DataMember]
    public string Question
    {
        get { return OriginalFlashcard.Answer; }
        set { OriginalFlashcard.Answer = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Answer
    {
        get { return OriginalFlashcard.Question; }
        set { OriginalFlashcard.Question = value; }
    }
}
```

Let's define a serializable collection of objects conforming to `IFlashcard`...

```
[CollectionDataContract (ItemName = "Flashcard")]
class DeckOfFlashcards : List<IFlashcard>
{
}
```

...and fill it with some flashcards:

```
Flashcard f1 = new Flashcard() { Question = "What do you get when you multiply 6 by 7?", Answer = "42" };
FlippedFlashcard f2 = new FlippedFlashcard { OriginalFlashcard = f1 }; 
DeckOfFlashcards myDeck = new DeckOfFlashcards();
myDeck.Add(f1);
myDeck.Add(f2);
f1.Question = "What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?";
Console.WriteLine(f2.Answer); // >> What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?
```

Until now, everything works as I want it to work. When I change the `Question` in f1 from "What do you get when you multiply 6 by 7?" to "What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?", the `Answer` in f2 reflects this change correctly:

```
f1.Question = "What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?";
Console.WriteLine(f2.Answer); // >> What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?
```

I want to serialize this collection and keep the references between instances of `Flashcard` and `FlippedFlashcard`. Here is my attempt:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type> { typeof(Flashcard), typeof(FlippedFlashcard) };
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DeckOfFlashcards), types, 100, false, true, null);
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Flashcards.xml", settings))
    dcs.WriteObject(writer, myDeck); // >> Question, Answer and OriginalFlashcard from f2 are serialized with "i:nil="true"
```

Unfortunately, the resulting Xml file lists `Question`, `Answer` and `OriginalFlashcard` from f2 as empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeckOfFlashcards xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="1" z:Size="2" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Foobar">
  <Flashcard z:Id="2" i:type="Flashcard">
    <Answer z:Id="3">42</Answer>
    <Question z:Id="4">What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?</Question>
  </Flashcard>
  <Flashcard z:Id="5" i:type="FlippedFlashcard">
    <Answer z:Ref="4" i:nil="true" />
    <OriginalFlashcard z:Ref="2" i:nil="true" />
    <Question z:Ref="3" i:nil="true" />
  </Flashcard>
</DeckOfFlashcards>
```

When I try to deserialize the collection from the file...

```
DeckOfFlashcards myOtherDeck;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("Flashcards.xml"))
    myOtherDeck = (DeckOfFlashcards)dcs.ReadObject(reader); // >> fires NullReferenceException at "set { OriginalFoo.Bar2 = value; }" with value "What is the answer to life, the universe and everything?"
```

...I get a `NullReferenceException`, probably when the Xml for the `FlippedFlashcard` is hit.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Please, oh please, don't post large chunks of code [filled with foo-bar](http://foobarisevil.com/) :'(

Comment: Sorry, but I honestly didn't know that foobar is evil these days. (I haven't posted a question in a long time.) Please accept my apologies.

Comment: no need to apologise, I just wanted to let you know that your code is really hard to follow and understand, and that might be way you're not getting any responses.

Comment: I rephrased the example completely. Hope this helps. I would love to post less code in order to raise the odds to get an answer, but I really don't know any shorter example to present the problem in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

In order to prevent the NullPointerException, it was necessary to review the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes. `interface IFlashcard` needs no contract at all:

```
interface IFlashcard
{
    string Question { get; set;  }
    string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

The code for `class Flashcard` remains unchanged, just as I wrote it in the description. The only real change necessary was to *remove* the `[DataMember]`attributes from  `Question` and `Answer` in `class FlippedFlashcard`, like this:

```
[DataContract]
class FlippedFlashcard : IFlashcard
{
    [DataMember]
    public Flashcard OriginalFlashcard { get; set; }

    public string Question
    {
        get { return OriginalFlashcard.Answer; }
        set { OriginalFlashcard.Answer = value; }
    }

    public string Answer
    {
        get { return OriginalFlashcard.Question; }
        set { OriginalFlashcard.Question = value; }
    }
}
```

Now everything works fine. :-)